# jquery outerWidth behavior browser differences

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When setting an elements width using outerWidth in chrome it returns the width as a decimal. However, in chrome and firefox it returns intergers.

The numbers being passed in are integers too. Example code below.

```
$(obj).outerWidth(50)
```

I'm just wondering if something else might be interfering with it and it's normal behavior or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There could be something interfering with this, outerWidth includes padding and border, and browsers each have different 'default' css. See this [link](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) about resetting, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. Jquery returns decimals in browsers that have this kind of precision, instead of just rounding.